# Does that mean that my RAM is broken?

Tags: memory, memtest86+

Memtest86+ has shown 4 passes and 19 errors, with 18 occurring in test 2, and one occurring in test 3.

Does this mean the ram is faulty, how should I go about diagnosing which ram module is causing the problem?

[image]

Comment: memtest86+ screen shoot: http://shrani.si/f/r/s/1hCvOMDz/20180814235249.jpg

Comment: "What is the easiest way to find which module is bad?" test each module individually.

Comment: @user9708792 - don't just post an image, explain what is in the image in case the image doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It looks like you may have two Super User accounts: [David](//superuser.com/users/934210) and [user9708792](//superuser.com/users/934064). If so, this will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer. Please take the time to utilise [this Help Center tutorial](//superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If this test result is repeatable, e.g. you get it every time you run the test, then yes your RAM is damaged or faulty.

Easiest way to test which module is affected is to test one module a time.

As noted by @djsmiley2k it may be something else that is causing test to fail. If you have an opportunity test RAM modules in another machine.

Comment: It's worth noting that only one test (and once on another test is failing), as tests are ran in series it could be also a bad power supply or something other than the ram causing the faults.

Answer (score 0):

I have added extra fans to blow air over the RAM. Seems they were getting too hot. Cleared up the bad memory issue.

Comment: Did you just make a new account?

Comment: It looks like you may have two Super User accounts: [David](//superuser.com/users/934210) and [user9708792](//superuser.com/users/934064). If so, this will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer. Please take the time to utilise [this Help Center tutorial](//superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts.